# drools adding fact types in excel file (declaring types)

Tags: excel, drools

I am looking on some example excel files to declare a Fact Type in the rule file. How can I add a a fact type in the excel file. I can do it in the drl file as given below.

```
package KieRule;

global java.util.List names;

declare Invoice
    cardType : String
    price : int
end

rule "HDFC"

when
    invoiceObject : Invoice(cardType=="HDFC" && price>10000);
then
    names.add( "discount for HDFC = 10" );
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution for that. Posting it here if it help others,

[image]